Is it possible to model a Second-order growth slope factor as a mediator of another second-order growth slope factor?
I am running a second-order growth model with three variables.
My data spans 7 waves of data. I am currently running a multivariate growth model
which models the associative relation of multiple growth factors.
I have heard that there is not a real consensus on whether the double-headed arrows which
show the associative relations of the growth factors can be changed into one-headed arrows
which will be a clearer indication of the direction of relationships among the factors.
Regardless, I was wondering if there is a way to model one of my three growth factors as a mediator of the other two. So,
growth slope factor A -> growth slope factor B (mediator) -> slope growth factor C
kind of model.
If anyone knows this kind of model, it will be really helpful to know.
Thank you always for your support.

Technically, it is certainly possible to specify such a model. Whether it makes sense is a substantive rather than statistical question. You would make the assumption that change in one variable causes change in another variable which then causes change in yet another variable. This could absolutely make sense. A first-order LGC mediation model is described on pages 209-213 in David MacKinnon's book on statistical mediation:
MacKinnon, D. (2012). Introduction to statistical mediation analysis. Routledge.
I see no problem (in principle) with generalizing such a model to 2nd order growth factors.
One issue here is temporal ordering. If all variables are measured on the same time points, it would be questionable whether you could convincingly demonstrate the mediation process with that design. But this is the same (or similar) issue as in cross-sectional analyses of mediation, which are widespread.

Sounds like it would be a beast of a model too, and would need to be very well specified to converge.

Thank you for the confirmation and information! I went and read the chapter you referred to and thought I would give it a try. Yes, it will be a hell of a beast to model, but it looks like something that is worth a try! Thank you again!
